# How to find values that occur specific number of times in Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, counter, series

Given the following Series:

```
sr = pd.Series([5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8])
```

I want to find the values that occur 3 times. This is my solution which seems to work but looks very strange:

```
(sr.value_counts() == 3)[sr.value_counts() == 3].index.values
```

Is there any other/obvious way I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is fine, you just shouldn't repeat the most expensive part, which is the counting. Store this in a variable and reuse. You may also not need to retrieve the underlying NumPy array, `pd.Index` objects are often sufficient:

```
sr = pd.Series([5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8])

counts = sr.value_counts()

res = counts[counts == 3].index
# Int64Index([8, 6, 5], dtype='int64')
```

The reason there's no ready-made method for what you want is any solution will require minimum O(*n*) time complexity, which is the complexity for `value_counts`. There's no way round this.

One alternative, `dict`-based `collections.Counter`, will be less efficient when it comes to filtering by count. Since NumPy arrays are stored efficiently in memory, Boolean filtering is efficient relative to dictionary iteration.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no ready-baked way, something like `where(value_counts() == 3`. (I searched through docs but could not find hence decided to ask here..)

Answer (score 2):

@jpp's answer is probably the one you should go with, but here is a weird alternative (just for fun):

```
sr.groupby(sr).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3).unique()
#array([5, 6, 8])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `loc`

```
sr.value_counts().loc[lambda x : x==3].index
Out[162]: Int64Index([8, 6, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Can you explain or give a reference to how a function works in `loc[]`?

Comment: @KorayTugay https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `.where`:

```
sr.where(sr.value_counts()==3).dropna().index

# Output:
Int64Index([5, 6, 8], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: This is what I was missing, `dropna`. Thank you. Very helpful.